# Embeddable in Datanucleus

Tags: java, jpa, datanucleus

I have the following model classes:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    private B b;
}

@Embeddable
public class B {
    ...
}
```

I'm using Spring MVC, the controller is annotated with @Transactional and I have the following datanucleus properties specified (amongst others)

```
datanucleus.detachAllOnCommit=true
datanucleus.detachAllOnClose=true
datanucleus.detachState=all
datanucleus.copyOnAttach=true
datanucleus.attachSameDatastore=true
datanucleus.maxFetchDepth=2
```

In the view (JSP), when the transaction should be over and the objects detached, if I try to access `${a.b.whatever}` I get this error

```
javax.jdo.JDODetachedFieldAccessException: You have just attempted to access field "b" yet this field was not detached when you detached the object. Either dont access this field, or detach it when detaching the object.
A.jdoGetb(A.java)
A.getB(A.java)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:62)
javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:123)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:935)
```

...

I'm using DataNucleus 3.1.3 with MySQL.

Any idea why this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
 @Basic(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

before

```
private B b;
```

This will make B eagerly fetched and make it properly detachable.

You can experiment with fetch groups to specify what should be fetched when.